# How to transform a number to letters in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have for ex this number 1202445.56 and I want to get in letters one million two hundred two thousands  four hundred forty four and fifty six?
It's possible to do this in both languages PHP and JavaScript? If yes, how?

Comment: You can split each character and then write a switch case which will return value in words. And yes it can be done in both language.

Comment: you will need to write a custom function, as fas as I know PHP doesn't have a built-in function for that :/